# Is there a way to retrieve `ColumnFamilyHandle` from `ColumnFamilyName` in RocksDb?

Tags: database, insert, rocksdb, column-family, rocksdb-java

Alternatively, is there a way to get all the currently open `ColumnFamilyHandles` from a db?

I am aware of the static function `RocksDB.listColumnFamilies`. But this returns a `List<byte[]> List containing the column family names`. Not sure if there is a way to get `ColumnFamilyHandle` from here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no API to retrieve the `ColumnFamilyHandle` after opening. You can only get the column_family_handle in [`Open()`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/875bfd75a09b4a456333702d538ce019c0a63716/include/rocksdb/db.h#L265), or when [creating new column_family](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/875bfd75a09b4a456333702d538ce019c0a63716/include/rocksdb/db.h#L311).